# 討伐補佐に数えとけよ meaning?

Tags: meaning

in Attack of the Titan season 2, ep4 at 8:16, there is this sentence:

> 今のちゃんと討伐補佐に数えとけよ

can anyone explain what it means? it doesn't seem to make sense to me. Count the support of conquest properly? also what is とけ at the end mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it gets rewritten as:

> 今の（を）ちゃんと[討伐補佐]{とうばつほさ}に数えておけよ

I think you get the gist of it.

But to make sure, though, 討伐, in this case, is the act of taking down the titan, and 補佐 is assistance. That whole phrase can be translated as just **kill assist**.

While 数える usually means **to count**, I'd translate it as **add on to** in this case.

The ておく form has a ton of meanings, but here it's just used to tell her that she should remember to add 1 assist to the report.

Altogether, it means something like:

> Make sure to add this one to the assist count!